# SSIS:The Flat File Connection Manager is unable to read fixed width txt file properly

Tags: ssis, notepad, flatfilesource

I need to read data from a fixed width txt file which will be put on the server and write that data to a SQL table through SSIS package.
The problem is that when I open the txt file in notepad, the data seems to be unformatted (first row seems distorted even after wordwrap):

Screenshot of original file:

[image]

But when I copy the data from notepad, paste it in wordpad, the data seems perfectly formatted. So, when I save this wordpad data as .txt and use it in my SSIS package, the package runs perfectly. But when I use the original file as shown in the screenshot above, the SSIS is unable to read it.

Screenshot of formatted file:

[image]

I am a beginner in SSIS and stuck on this issue since many days. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "even after wordwrap"?

Comment: What error does SSIS give when trying to read the original .txt file? Where did the original .txt file come from?